# Organizing SQL Scripts - Best Practices

Tags: sql, database, organized

So this is not a technical one, forgive me in advance if it's not the right place...

I've recently began to write many SQL scripts, I have previous SQL skills, but was never in a position where this was my main agenda, and my scripts count grow every day.

I can't figure out the best way to organize all my scripts because some are tests / production / dev / procedures etc, which made me wonder if there are any tools or practices which can help and assist in this stage, because right now I'm in a bit of a mess.

Thanks in advance for any answers or comments.

Comment: Check out tools like Liquibase or Flyway

Comment: Or maybe just some version control like `git`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks will check it

Comment: @dnoeth I'm actually currently using Git for managing the scripts, was just wondering if there is a more SQL oriented tool